# why am i getting: Access denied for user 'traffic2'@'localhost' (using password: NO) for mysqlslap

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

sorry for the stupid question but have never used this and need to stress test my mySql database and think this will be a good place to start by using mysqlslap

can any one help please? i want to run it in my dev environment first
when i connect to mySql i have:

```
mysql -u traffic2 -p traffic2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified the password incorrectly; the syntax should be -

```
mysql -u traffic2 -ptraffic2
```

or

```
mysql -u traffic2 --p=traffic2
```

[Password option reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password)

Comment: the command i gave is exactly how i use it

    ~$ mysql -u traffic2 -p traffic2
Enter password: 

never had a problem and connect each time..it is correct as it is :)

Comment: Then `traffic2` is a database name, right? Next question - Is the password empty string?

Comment: when i type in the command, it asks for a password and i type in the password..it is not an empty string :)

Comment: Very strange. Cannot reproduce it. Try to connect with another account.

Comment: let me just state that: i run php: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.10 i found the mysqlslap and mysql executibles in /usr/bin/ and i run symfony 1.4.2

Comment: and when i run: helloises@helloise:~/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix$ ls -lah /usr/bin/mysqlslap i get:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 45K 2011-02-10 10:55 /usr/bin/mysqlslap

Comment: Tried mysqlslap tool. All is OK. Can you connect with another account?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by "account"

Comment: i have tried "root" my username="helloises" also tried to connect using user "rainbowcode" and got same error :(  i installed mytop and configured it with same username,password and dbname as stated in databases.yml ran mytop and that worked :)

Comment: Maybe something is with your users. Try to add new user and re-connect with new account.

Comment: i have done some investigation, ran this on mysql: select User,Host,password,Select_priv,Insert_priv,Delete_priv,Create_priv,Drop_priv  from mysql.user;
 and found all these privileges set for user root and host = localhost but not for user traffic2 and host = localhost..is this the problem? thank you

Comment: No, this is not a problem. Maybe the password is wrong or somthing else. I'm not sure. Can you create new account?

Comment: i finally managed to get it to work with setting priviliges for user= traffic2. thank you very much for the help!